# How to disable back button in activity for dialog

Tags: android, popupwindow, android-dialog

I have a problem that I want to handle back button event in a PopUpWindow(Dialog box) instead of a activity. I implemented OnKeyListner,... but it is not working

Here is my PopUpWindow

```
public class PopUp extends PopupWindow implements OnKeyListener{
...
@Override
  public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean not working?

Comment: where did you setOnKeyListener()?

Comment: are you showing this PopupWindow in Activity? if yes, override onBackPressed() method of Activity and call relevant code in PopupWindow which you want to handle... don't call super.onBackPressed() here

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the `onKeyDown` event

```
@Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
      return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
```

And you need to set the listener on your PopupWindow's content view

```
PopupWindow.this.getContentView().setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

You need to set up the key listener manually

Comment: Just updated my answer, i think the OP did not set a listener.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, i tried to do but, cannot override onKeyDown.

Comment: you are implementing the `OnKeyListener` interface. do you call the setOnKeyListener on the the PopupWindow instance?

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Do Here what ever you want do on back press;

}
```

and things should work for you. If you want to *specifically* do something on back_pressed, then write the code for that inside this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow a tricky way

create an object of your PopupWindow for your activity scope. as 
`private PopupWindow localPopup;...` and also create boolean flag to identify the popupwindow state

Create one private method to handle popupwindow as follow

```
private boolean actionOnPopupWindow(){
   if(isPopupWindowShowing){
       localPopup.dismiss();
       return false;
   }else
       return true;
}
```

Handle the popup window from onBackPress() method of your activity as follow

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(actionOnPopupWindow()
       super.onBackPressd();
}
```